# How to remove a particular row in sheet if one of its cell value contains string which has Total/total

Tags: excel, vba

I need to delete a row if one of its cell contains value which has total in it.

like cell value = total-abcd , total-abc
like if cell value contains total/Total it can be case sensitive .I have to delete it
Range will be any row in the sheet.

Comment: Why not try a case-insensitive `Find` for "total"?  If the returned range is not Nothing, delete the row.

Comment: Could you please help me with the expression or vba code?

Answer (score 0):

The macro below does what you seek.  However, it is difficult to imagine a simpler macro.  Do you have any idea how I created this macro or how to use it?  Please indicate how much you know about VBA and I will try to get you started if you need that level of help.

```
Option Explicit
Sub DeleteTotalsRow()

  ' Find a row containing "total" (any case) and delete it.

  ' 27Apr20  Coded.

  Dim Rng As Range

  With Worksheets("Data")

    Set Rng = .Cells.Find(What:="total", After:=.Range("A1"), LookIn:=xlFormulas2, _
                          LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                          SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, _
                          SearchFormat:=False)
    If Rng Is Nothing Then
      ' Totals row not found
    Else
      .Rows(Rng.Row).EntireRow.Delete
    End If
  End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Hello , much thanks for the code . I have implemented it but getting Application defined or object defined error.

Comment: Which line gives the error?  Have you replaced "Data" with the name of your worksheet?

Comment: yes I replaced it with my sheet name.Code is executing till this part :-Sub DeleteTotalsRow()

  ' Find a row containing "total" (any case) and delete it.

  ' 27Apr20  Coded.

  Dim Rng As Range

  With Worksheets("Sheet1")

    Set Rng = .Cells.Find(What:="total", After:=.Range("A1"), LookIn:=xlFormulas2, _
                          LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                          SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, _
                          SearchFormat:=False)

Comment: Are you saying execution stopped on `Set Rng = .Cells ...`?

Comment: If you were interested, I planned to show you how I had created this macro by using the Macro Recorder and then tidying the code.  I use Office 365 and I am concerned this code uses an option new to Office 365.  In particular, I cannot find any documentation that says `LookIn:=xlFormulas2` is valid.  Please replace with `LookIn:=xlValues` and try again.

Comment: Hey I have replaced it with Lookin:= XlValues. But nothing happend yet code executed successfully

Comment: I read the title of your question more carefully than the body.  Try `What:="total-*"`.

Comment: Amazing it worked , thanyou so much. Can total be case sensitive because it is not delete with cell value contains "total' - Still will work

Comment: `MatchCase:=False` is what makes it case insensitive.  Change to `MatchCase:=True` to make it case sensitive.